# Why although i'm allocating more memory with malloc in a variable, when i print the variable's size it still shows less memory/bytes?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, allocation

For example, you have the language c code:

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(8);
```

for some reason, if i print the size of the pointer p, even though it has 8 bytes (as i allocated it with malloc) it shows 4 when i print it:

```
printf("%i", sizeof(p)); // results on 4
```

i know that the default size of an integer is 4, but i'm allocating more memory than that with malloc, i'm allocating 8 bytes and it's still printing 4 when i do sizeof, why is that happening?

Comment: Given `int *p = ...` and `sizeof(p)` is the size of a pointer.  Why is 4 not reasonable for a pointer?  If code was `int x = 42;`, would your expect `sizeof(x)` to be 4 or 42?

Comment: the size should be 8 because i allocated 8 for the pointer with malloc, and when i print it's not, it's 4, that's what i'm not understanding.

Comment: `sizeof(p)` is the size of the object `p`,  not its value from some assignment.  `p` is a pointer, so its size here should be and is 4.

Comment: so how do i do to extract the size of object p? (which is 8) in code?

Comment: If `malloc` returns a non-`NULL` pointer value, the size is `8`, the amount you requested in `malloc(8)`. So if you want to know the size, it comes from the same place that the `8` came from.

Comment: *the size should be 8 because i allocated 8 for the pointer* No.  You allocated 8 bytes for the memory *pointed to by* the pointer.

Comment: "how do i do to extract the size of object p? (which is 8)", No,  the object is a _pointer_.  Its size is 4.  Use `sizeof(p)` to get the size of the pointer `p`.  To get the amount allocated, code knows it is 8 if `malloc()` returned non-`NULL`.  Keep track of the 8.

Comment: To be clear the size of the pointer `p` is not related to anything assigned to it, including some allocation.   A more reasonable question would be, "given the _value_ of an allocation, (return value from `malloc()`) how to find the amount of memory allocated?  (There is no portable solution).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer will give you the size of the pointer itself, which is typically `4` bytes on 32-bit platforms and `8` bytes on 64-bit platforms.

Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer will **not** give you any information about the size of the object that the pointer is pointing to. In particular, if the pointer is pointing to the result of a `malloc` allocation, it will not provide any information about the size of this allocation. You must keep track of the size of the allocation yourself, for example by storing it in a separate variable, because the C standard library does not provide any way of obtaining this information.